# Find all $x\in \mathbb Z$ for which $y=x^3-8x^2+20x-13$ is a prime number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers, integers, cubics

**Question :** Find all $x\in \mathbb Z$ for which $y=x^3-8x^2+20x-13$ is a prime number

---

I don't know how to start here. By Brute-Forcing, I could start plugging $x=1,2,3,...$ but that's very inefficient. If $y$ was a quadratic expression, I would have easily applied the Sridharacharya Formula, but that's not the case here.

Is there any other method or trick for this question, other than hit and trial?

Comment: $x-1$ is a factor, so what does this mean for the possible solutions to this question?

Comment: @abiessu Yes, I know that this cubic has 1 real root ($x=1$) and two other complex roots. Though I'm not sure how this helps in solving this question :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $x=1$, we get $y=0$.

So, we see that $y$ is divisible by $x-1$ to have
$$y=(x-1)(x^2-7x+13)$$

In order for this to be a prime, we have to have
$$x-1=\pm 1\qquad\text{or}\qquad x^2-7x+13=\pm 1$$
which implies 
$$x=0,2,3,4$$
giving
$$y=-13,3,2,3$$
respectively.

So, the answer is $x=2,3,4$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Note that $$f(x) = (x-1)(x^2-7x+13)$$ If $x$ is an integer, then both factors of $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, if $f(x)$ is prime, the two factors should be $\pm 1$ and $\pm p$, where $p$ is a prime.

Equate both factors to $\pm 1$ and take the intersection of the set of solutions.